# Event on second tap doesn't working with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a container with inside some text. 
On the desktop view the text appears on hover.
Click on the container open a link

On the mobile view I use "ontouchstart" to make appear the text and I use event.preventDefault to disable to open the link. So, with the first tap the text appears and I would like to open the link with the second tap.
The first tap add a class to a container and I made a function with this class but it's triggered on the first tap. What's wrong?

HTML

```
<a href="https://...." class="link" ontouchstart="firstTap(event, this)">
    <div class="container">...</div>
</a>
```

JS

```
function firstTap(event, el) {
    event.preventDefault()
    jQuery(el).addClass('active')
}

$(document).on('tap', '.link.active', function() {
    link = jQuery(this).attr('href')
    window.open(link,'_self',false)     
});
```

Comment: *what's wrong* - looks like "ontouchstart" is fired before the "tap" for the *same tap*.  It's like mousedown+click - the second event fires because you've added an event handler *before* the tap event.  You can add a setTimeout around the addclass active to wait until the tap has completed.

Comment: thanks! with setTimeout works :-)